# Query with left join and count in select works in MySQL but not in MS SQL Server 2012

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following two tables:
**SURVEY**
id: INT (PK) 
title: VARCHAR 
description: TEXT

**QUESTIONNAIRE**
id: INT (PK) 
title: VARCHAR 
survey_id: INT (FK on survey.id)

[Screenshot of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C4VL.png)

I want to sellect all surveys along with the number of questionnaires that each survey has so i tried the following query:

```
SELECT s.id, s.title, s.description, count(q.id)  
FROM  survey s  
LEFT OUTER JOIN questionnaire q  ON q.survey_id = s.id  
GROUP BY s.id
```

**I tried the query in MySQL and it works great.**
The problem is  i need to use **MS SQL SERVER 2012** where the same
query does not work.

First i got the following error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'survey.title' is invalid
>   in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause

.

then i tried:

```
 SELECT s.id, s.title, s.description, count(q.id)  
 FROM  survey s  
 LEFT OUTER JOIN questionnaire q  
   ON q.survey_id = s.id  
 GROUP BY s.id, s.title, s.description
```

which reslted in the following error:

> Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 4  The text, ntext, and image data
>   types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE
>   operator.

If i remove the s.description (which is TEXT) from the SELECT and GROUP BY the query works but this is no solution.

Any ideas ?
Thank you

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the quick response. I tried the query you proposed but i got a  "Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "q.id" could not be bound"  error

Comment: No, sorry. I did this now and i got the previous error again: "Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator."

Comment: Bummer, sorry, I'll clean out my comments.

Comment: @TomField see my answer, it's because of your description column type, just change it to use nvarchar(max)

Comment: You are right Thomas. I didn't know TEXT is going to be depricated. So i guess this is the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

text is deprecated - try nvarchar(max) or varchar(max)

[ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

The left may be the problem but I get you want it.

If nvarchar(max) or varchar(max) does not fix it then try this

```
SELECT s.id, s.title, s.description, sq.cc  
 FROM  survey s  
 join ( SELECT ss.id, count(qq.id) as cc 
          FROM  survey ss  
          LEFT OUTER JOIN questionnaire q  
                ON q.survey_id = s.id  
         GROUP BY s.id 
      ) sq 
   on sq.id = s.id
```

Comment: Hi Frisbee,
Replacing text with nvarchar works. I didn't know text is going to be depricated so i didn't want to replace it with nvarchar. So i guess your answer is the correct one!
Thanks!

Comment: If that was the answer then consider giving it the check

Answer (score 0):

I think you should learn how Group By and aggregate functions work.  This would prove greatly effective in your quest to understanding T-SQL.  Here is a link that may help you out.

[Group By Information](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Also, this may not be the case at all but why Text for the description and not varchar in MS SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 0):

You use an aggregate function and a non aggregate function you have to join your table with itself and use the group by function on the column you want to have the count for

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your Description column type :

> Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 4 The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

If you change the type of the column to `nvarchar(max)` you will be able to perform your group by.

Answer (score 0):

As well as changing the column datatype in the table (or casting to `VARCHAR(MAX)` at run time) you could also use

```
SELECT s.id,
       s.title,
       s.description,
       COALESCE(q.cnt,0) AS cnt
FROM   survey s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(q.id) AS cnt,
                               q.survey_id
                        FROM   questionnaire q
                        GROUP  BY q.survey_id) q
                    ON q.survey_id = s.id
```

to avoid having to `GROUP BY` that column at all